# How can I keep my PDF files from appearing in search engines?

Tags: search, pdf

I am trying to sell ebooks on my website.  The ebooks are in the form of PDF files.  The customers pay to download them with Paypal.  But if I type the beginning of the ebook into the google search the PDF file comes up.   Anyone can then open the PDF file.  I have tried this on someone else's computer and the same thing happens.

Thus, the question is, how can I keep my PDF files from appearing in Google and other search engines?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about webmaster activities and not about programming.

Answer (score 2):

I'll list two solutions in order of complexity.

1. Use a [robots.txt file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) to prevent your PDF files from being indexed by Google. That will prevent further indexing, however, if someone knows the exact addresses to your PDF files, they can still share the links and download them without paying.
2. Store the PDF files in a directory outside your Web server root, but which is still readable by the server itself. When someone buys your e-book, register their purchase in a database and send them a customized download link via e-mail. This link will point to a script on your server which will check the purchase into the database. If the user is authorized to download the file, the script will open the right PDF file on the server, read it and pass through its contents to the Web browser. The browser, depending on how the script was made and on the user's preferences, could open the PDF inline (in the browser window) or ask the user to download it. This is the best way to handle downloads as knowledge of the customized download link is required, and you could also block downloads from a specific user in case he/she gives away his/her personal link.

Either way, since the URLs to your e-books have been exposed, you should change them AND ask Google to remove the old addresses via [its tools for Webmasters](http://www.google.com/webmasters/).

Answer (score 2):

Putting unencrypted PDF files online in a way that allows access without prior authorization will always be insecure, since once the link to the PDF is publicly known, anybody will be able to download it. Therefore you should seriously reconsider your distribution strategy.

[One time download links](http://www.webvamp.co.uk/blog/coding/creating-one-time-download-links/) and sending the PDF by mail after a successful purchase are probably the best options.

Until then you might want to replace the PDF with an password-protected RAR file and only give the password to paying customers. This obviously is also insecure and requires decompression software capable of handling encrypted RAR files.

In order to address the issue of your PDF being found by Google and other search engines, you should read about [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard). However this is not a solution, since not all web crawlers will honor the content of the robots.txt file.

I also believe that you probably don't know about the Internet Archive. This site takes snapshots of websites which might include a copy of your publicly available PDFs.